# Отправка данных с формы на почту JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, у меня есть две формы

```
<form class="order-form" method="post">
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden" for="name-field-one">Ваше имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name-field-one" placeholder="Имя" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш телефон</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" id="number-field-one" placeholder="Телефон" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email-field-one" placeholder="Email">
          </p>
          <p>
            <button  class="order-button" type="submit">Отправить</button>
          </p>
        </form>
```

и

```
<form class="modal-form" method="post">
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden" for="name-field-two">Ваше имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name-field-two" placeholder="Имя" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш телефон</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" id="number-field-two" placeholder="Телефон" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email-field-two" placeholder="Email">
          </p>
          <p>
            <button  class="order-button modal-btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
          </p>
        </form>
```

Необходимо чтобы данные с формы отправлялись на почту, я видел реализацию данной задачи на php, вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать на чистом js или jquery и будет ли это верным решением? Если да, то как? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Для кнопки "Отправить" в первой форме в js у меня прописано preventDefault, будет ли это влиять на отправку данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на просторах гугла этот плагин [jquery.textmistake](http://tarampampam.github.io/jquery.textmistake/). Статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246347/). Вы при этом не пишете код на сервере, плагин сделает всё сам, думаю разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я правильно понимаю, что такую задачу без использования сторонних сервисов без работы с сервером не решить? В любом случае использовать лучше php?

Comment: да, вместе с jquery ajax, если хотите без обновления страницы